# Insufficient Privileges for partner portal user

Tags: salesforce-id, partner-portal

I have created a Vf page and created a tab to view Vf page. But when i try to go to this tab i am getting message - (Insufficient Privileges. You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. )   This user is partner portal user. Can anybody guide me what i need to change to get this page access for partner portal user .

Comment: Have you ensured the user's profile has access to the VF page?

Comment: No i am looking over it. Can you please guide me how to give access to VF page to partner portal user

Comment: If you find a partner portal user record inside Salesforce, it should have a link through to their profile. I'm not sure if you can customise the standard one, you might need to clone it, reassign the user, and then edit the cloned profile to add access to the particular VF page (there's a VF specific section).

Comment: Was it through updating the profile? If so I'll write up the answer, if it wasn't then you should write up an answer so others can learn from this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the the security setting and added the profile to access the VF page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give access to the user for that page and class as  a partner user created by a account and contact record, you just open the users list and click on the partner user and the go to profile of that user and check the access of the tab , vfp and class associated with tab.

How give the access to the page
http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/users_profiles_orig_ui_editing.htm